# How to add a css font-family?

Tags: css, font-family

I downloaded the font-family Tokyo-Outline, but it won't apply. This is not just a problem with this font all font changes that aren't within css don't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Tokyo-Outline';
                src: url('Tokyo-Outline.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('Tokyo-Outline.otf')  format('opentype'),
                        url('Tokyo-Outline.woff') format('woff'), url('Tokyo-Outline.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('Tokyo-Outline.svg#Tokyo-Outline') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }


            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                font-family: 'Tokyo-Outline';
            }

            body{
                background-color: rgb(244, 129, 83);
                
            }

            .all{
                position:absolute;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                margin-left:-100px;/* half width*/
                margin-top:-300px;/* half height*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="all">
            <form class="input">
                <h3> List</h3><input type="text" id="type"><button id="add">&#43;</button>
            </form>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am adding filler text because apparently "I don't have enough details." You don't have to read this. Well I have a pink cactus with a green stem.

Comment: are you sure the font has the good path?

Comment: As @pual says, font path would be the first thing to check. After that, try your browser's Inspector, and see what it says about whether the fonts are loaded. (There's a reason you're asked for more details - context is really useful, as are the things you've tried already.)

Comment: This is a problem with Google Fonts too, which I think has a good path

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the url path? For example do you have them in a font folder? If so, try something like: url('fonts/Tokyo-Outline.eot').